# Proving a key theorem for an additive but not sigma additive measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am confused by a maths book I am reading. It says: let $\mu$ be a measure that is additive but not $\sigma$ additive, prove that theorem 1 still continues to hold, despite the non-$\sigma$ additivity. And this theorem 1 is the following:

Theorem 1:
Let $\mu$ be a $\sigma$ additive measure on a semiring $F_{\mu}$, and suppose the sets $A,A_{1},A_{2},A_{3} $... where $A_{1},A_{2},A_{3}... $are pairwise disjoint sets of $A$, all belong to $F_{\mu}$, then

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }\mu\left ( A_{k} \right )\leqslant \mu\left ( A \right )$

Does this theorem 1 really hold without $\sigma$ additivity? If so, how do I prove it? I am confused because the theorem appears to require $\sigma$ additivity to hold. I am sort of wondering if it is a mistake in the book.

Answer (score 2):

The theorem does indeed hold without the $\sigma$-additive assumption. For any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $A_{1},\ldots,A_{n}$ are pairwise disjoint. Hence, $\mu(A_{1}\cup\cdots\cup A_{n})=\mu(A_{1})+\cdots+\mu(A_{n})$. We also know that $A_{1}\cup\cdots\cup A_{n}\subset A$. Using the monotonicity of $\mu$, this gives that 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\mu(A_{k})=\mu\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}A_{k}\right)\leq\mu(A).
$$
Since this result holds for all $n$, it follows that 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_{k}):=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\mu(A_{k})\leq \mu(A).
$$

The idea is that the proof only requires we examine finitely many of the $A_{k}$'s are a time. Hence, countable additivity is not actually needed.

Comment: So, to emphasize this: the second part (going from the inequality witn $n$ to the inequality with $\infty$) is no longer about measures, but just about real series.